# How to display three figures in the same line?

Tags: subfig

I try to display three figures in the same line:

```
\begin{figure*}[ht!]
   \subfloat[\label{fig:PKR}]{%
      \includegraphics[ width=0.31\textwidth]{./images/fig1.png}}
\hspace{\fill}
   \subfloat[\label{fig:PKT} ]{%
      \includegraphics[ width=0.31\textwidth]{./images/fig2.png}}
\hspace{\fill}
   \subfloat[\label{fig:tie5}]{%
      \includegraphics[ width=0.31\textwidth]{./images/fig3.png}}\\
\caption{\label{workflow}Comparaison between different states. (a) fig1; (b)fig2; (c) fig3.}
\end{figure*}
```

It works but with giving me this error:

```
! LaTeX Error: No counter 'subfigure@save' defined.
See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
```

Could you please help me.

Comment: Please tell us (a) which document class you employ and (b) whether you load the `subfig` or the `subfigure` package. (FWIW, I get no error messages if I employ the `IEEEtran` document class and the `subfig` package.)

Comment: Coukd you post a *complete* (compilable) code?

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from your code i gueassing, that you have two column document. with stabdard `article` document class with necessary packages (`subfig` and `grasphics`) it works fine:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure*}[ht!]
   \subfloat[fig. 1 \label{fig:PKR}]{%
      \includegraphics[ width=0.31\textwidth]{./images/fig1.png}}
\hspace{\fill}
   \subfloat[fig. 2 \label{fig:PKT} ]{%
      \includegraphics[ width=0.31\textwidth]{./images/fig2.png}}
\hspace{\fill}
   \subfloat[fig. 3 \label{fig:tie5}]{%
      \includegraphics[ width=0.31\textwidth]{./images/fig3.png}}\\
\caption{Comparison between different states.}
    \label{workflow}
\end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

however, what is going on in your document we can't know, if you will not provide more information about it (used document class, which packages are loaded in preamble).